# What loop should I use for this kind of data in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I have a list of data with 3 columns Status, Next Status and Default(0,1). How can i loop through the data and get the last status where Default = 1.

This is my table looks like.

```
ID        Status    Next Status    Default
--------------------------------
 1          PASS       FAIL           0
 2          PASS       HOLD           0
 3          PASS       RELE           1
 4          FAIL       EXEM           0
 5          FAIL       HOLD           1
 6          HOLD       RELE           0
 7          RELE       HOLD           0
 8          RELE       CANC           0
```

Example my `Status` is `PASS`, now it will loop in the table and check what will be the last status that is default = 1.

Samle1 : PASS  - RELE   - 1

Since RELE in the next status it will look at RELE.

RELE CANC 0 when the next status default become 0 then it will get RELE.

Comment: Would you like to get most recent "Next Status" value where "Default" = 1 and "Status" = PASS ?

Comment: Also, is there a unique row identifier in your table ?if not, then you should have one

Comment: Relational data doesn't have an order in and of itself. If you want this sorted in order, you need another column, i.e. one with a timestamp. With that, the solution would be easy.

Comment: Yes, to re-iterate what @R.J.Dunnill said - while your list above is ordered top to bottom, there is no such default ordering in a relational database, even though it may appear that they come out in the order they go in. That may be the case sometimes, but can and does change depending on lots of things, such as indexes. If you need a persistent row id then you need to define it in the table. Once you do, you will never do this with a `loop`, that's procedural thinking. Its likely to be a recursive CTE that answers it.

Comment: Also, assuming these are numbered 1 through 8, I can see how your first example moves from PASS to RELE, but I have no idea what the second half of your explanation means.

Comment: Sorry for my explanation, what i want to get is the next status that is DEfault = 1 and thaat next status is default = 0.

Comment: Example:
Current Status is PASS      RELE       1
Since the 2 RELE in the bottom dont have a default then it stops there and get RELE.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a list of data with 3 columns Status, Next Status and
>   Default(0,1). How can i loop through the data and get the last status
>   where Default = 1.
>
> This is my table looks like.
>
> ```
> Status    Next Status    Default
> --------------------------------
> PASS       FAIL           0
> PASS       HOLD           0
> PASS       RELE           1
> FAIL       EXEM           0
> FAIL       HOLD           1
> HOLD       RELE           0
> RELE       HOLD           0
> RELE       CANC           0
> ```
>
> Example my Status is PASS, now it will loop in the table and check
>   what will be the last status that is default = 1.
>
> Samle1 : PASS - RELE - 1
>
> Since RELE in the next status it will look at RELE.
>
> RELE CANC 0 when the next status default become 0 then it will get
>   RELE.

I am not sure if I am understanding the requirement correctly.

Here is my understanding: For any given status, you need to figure out its previous status (if any) which had a default = 1. And I understand that the 'status' column value is the previous status of a given value of 'next status' column in a row. Please correct me if my this understanding is wrong.

With this understanding, here are the 2 queries depending on what is your input to this program:

1. Is status going to be an input to the query? If so:

   ```
   SELECT  DISTINCT
           S.Status
           ,LastStatus = OA.Status 
   FROM    Status S
           OUTER APPLY (
                           SELECT  TOP 1 SI.Status
                           FROM    Status SI
                           WHERE   SI.[Next Status] = S.Status
                           AND     SI.Default = 1
                       ) OA
   WHERE   S.Status = '<input status name>';
   ```

   2> If you rather need to retrieve this for each status available in the status column of 
   the table, then:

   ```
   SELECT  DISTINCT
           S.Status
           ,LastStatus = OA.Status 
   FROM    Status S
           OUTER APPLY (
                           SELECT  TOP 1 SI.Status
                           FROM    Status SI
                           WHERE   SI.[Next Status] = S.Status
                           AND     SI.Default = 1
                       ) OA;
   ```